# Error installing rPython (scrdir)

Tags: r, rpython

I am trying to install rPython but I get the following error about the scrdir installation. The scr file (`makevars.win`), as well as the `configure.win` file have the same path.
The path I am using is:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo PKG_LIBS=-LD:/Programs/Python27/libs -lpython27
echo PKG_CFLAGS=-I"D:/Programs/Python27/include"
```

And this is the error I get on R.

```
install("D:/Programs/R-3.4.2/library/rPython")
Installing rPython
"D:/Programs/R-3.4.2/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "D:/Programs/R-3.4.2/library/rPython" --library="D:/Programs/R-3.4.2/library" --install-tests 

ERROR: cannot install to srcdir for package 'rPython'
* removing 'D:/Programs/R-3.4.2/library/rPython'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I am using a windows 10 machine 64 bits. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by adding "`C:/Rtools`" to the variable Path in the "`environment variables`" of my computer.